# Check if dictionary items occurs "similarly"

Tags: python, list, dictionary, counter

I am trying to implement a function which checks whether a counter contains "similar" percentage of each items. That is

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(["Dog", "Cat", "Dog", "Horse", "Dog"])
size = 5
lst = list(c.values())
percentages = [x / size * 100 for x in lst]  # [60.0, 20.0, 20.0]
```

How can I check whether those `percentages` are all "similar"? I would like to apply the [`math.isclose`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_math_isclose.asp) method with `abs_tol=2` but it takes two arguments not the entire list.

In the example, items do *not* occurs similarly.

This method will be used for checking whether a training set of labels is balanced or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to pick the minimum and maximum value of the percentages list and pass those to `isclose()`

```py
from math import isclose
from collections import Counter


def is_balanced(lst, abs_tol):
    c = Counter(lst)
    total = c.total()
    percentages = [(v / total) * 100 for v in c.values()]
    return isclose(min(percentages), max(percentages), abs_tol=abs_tol)


lst1 = ["Dog", "Cat", "Dog", "Horse", "Dog"]
lst2 = ["Dog", "Cat", "Horse"]

print(is_balanced(lst1, 2))  # False
print(is_balanced(lst2, 2))  # True
```

Comment: @tail Thanks for mentioning `c.total()`. Didn't know about it.

Comment: @S.B New in v.3.10. Not available in previous Python's versions.

Answer (score 0):

Using `np.isclose()`:

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np

def is_balanced(lst) -> bool:
   c = Counter(lst)
   fractions = np.asarray(list(c.values())) / len(lst)
   return np.isclose(fractions, 1 / len(c)).all()
```

See the [doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) of `np.isclose()` for arguments like `atol`, `rtol`, etc.

Comment: I think this is not adding nothing new with respect to the accepted answer.